# Technically speaking wouldn't this be a way of deleting the last node? LL C++

Tags: c++

```
node *head, *current, *temp;
current = head;
while(NULL != current){
  temp = current;
  current = current->next;
}
delete current;
current = temp;
current->next = NULL;
```

I'm just wondering I know there's something like this and there's recursion, assuming there's already a linked list and we don't know how many nodes are in the list.

By delete I mean deallocate.

```
node *head, *current, *temp;
current = head;
while(NULL != current->next){
  temp = current;
  current = current->next;
}
if (NULL != current){
delete current;
current = temp;
current->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur you are right that it exits the loop with a null pointer in `current`, but deleting a null pointer has no ill side-effects. A segmentation fault would mean a non-conformant implementation.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Linked List?

Comment: While traversing through the list, temp is always one before current.  I delete current, which is the last node, and current gets assigned temp, and I set temp->next to node which cuts off the list right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not do anything: the exit condition of the loop is `NULL == current`, meaning that `delete current;` will *always* pass `NULL` to `delete`. This is OK, but it does not de-allocate anything.

You should change your loop to stop when `current->next == NULL`, but you must be extra careful to make sure that you do not dereference `current` when it is equal to `NULL`:

```
temp = 0;
while(current && current->next){
    temp = current;
    current = current->next;
}
if (temp) {
    delete current;
    temp->next = 0;
}
```

**EDIT :** Your edited code mimics my answer to a large extent, except yours would fail if `head == NULL`. It would also fail if the list has exactly one node, because `temp` would remain unassigned.

Comment: @user1858740 For the pre-edit code, yes, that would be right: `while(NULL != current)` means the *post-condition* of the loop is `current == NULL`. At that time, `tmp` points to the last node, which has its `next` pointing to `NULL` already, so the last assignment has no effect as well. Please also see my last edit to the answer.

Comment: Okay got it thanks! I remember the my professor saying something about checking ->next for NULL for traversing but I guess I forgot.

Comment: But head is not NULL in the question it says, given that the was already a list + there were other nodes

Answer (score 1):

You are exiting the loop when the pointer is null and the delete it. That's not going to work.

I guess you meant to delete `temp` instead ? That would still not work with your current code.

Comment: Deleting null is perfectly valid, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this:

```
while (NULL != next) {
  prev = current;
  current = next;
  next = current->next;
}
delete current;
if (NULL != prev) {
  prev->next = NULL;
}
```